# Jmeter - How to check if less than 10 stylesheets are loading when I open a web page

Tags: jmeter

I have a requirement where I need to verify that when I open a web page, there should less than 10 stylesheets and less than 20 .js are loading. Is there a way to do this in Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

It is, but you will need to do some scripting. Example solution:

1. Add [Beanshell Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Assertion) as a child of the HTTP Request you need to test.
2. Put the following code into the Beanshell Assertion "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.jmeter.samplers.SampleResult;

   int js, css;
   js = css = 0;

   for (SampleResult subResult : SampleResult.getSubResults()) {
       if (subResult.getUrlAsString().endsWith(".css")) {
           css++;
       } else if (subResult.getUrlAsString().endsWith(".js")) {
           js++;
       }
   }

   log.info("JS files: " + js);   // you can comment or remove these lines
   log.info("CSS files: " + css); // as they do nothing but print the numbers to jmeter.log

   if (css > 10 || js > 20) {
       Failure = true;
       FailureMessage = "Exceeded maximum scripts/styles";
   }
   ```

   [image: JMeter Beanshell Assertion CSS JS]
3. If any of the specified thresholds will be met, the sampler will get failed with the relevant message:

   [image: Assertion Failure Message]

More information on conditionally failing JMeter tests: [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps)

Comment: Thank  you! I tried it, but for some reason I am getting the count as 0. I am able to see in fiddler that there are css and js files loading. What could I be doing wrong?